# Puppeteer page.evaluate returns empty object

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So I was trying to create a function that returns object from fetch. Code below is working:

```
const edit = async (y) => {
        const option = 
        {
            "something": y          
         };
        const editItem = await page.evaluate(async option => {
            return fetch('https://example.com/x', {
                body           : JSON.stringify({x:option.something})
                referrerPolicy : 'no-referrer-when-downgrade',
                method         : 'POST',
                mode           : 'cors'
            }).then(response => {
                const responseJson = response.json();
                return responseJson;
            })
        }, option);
        return editItem;
    };
```

But I wanted to create it in that way:

```
const edit = async (x) => {
        const option = 
        {
            "something": x        
         };
        const editItem = await page.evaluate(async option => {
            const editedItem = await fetch('https://example.com/x', {
                body           : JSON.stringify({x:option.something}),
                referrerPolicy : 'no-referrer-when-downgrade',
                method         : 'POST',
                mode           : 'cors'
            })
            const editedItemJson = await editedItem.json();
            return editedItemJson;
        }, option);
    return editItem;
};
```

But it keeps returning empty object. What should I change?

Comment: Both patterns work fine for me. Can you share a [mcve]? As an aside, `async` is pointless in a function that doesn't use `await`, as is the case in the top example, and the extra `await editedItem.json()` is also extra -- you can just `return editedItem.json()` and Puppeteer will await it for you before returning from `page.evaluate`.