# puppeteer page.evaluate returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

im trying to scrape a price element from a website using the `page.evaluate` method, but it allways returns {} when i `console.log` the result. here's the code:

```
const browser = await pptr.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto("url")
const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector("selector")
})
console.log(price) // returns {}
```

I've tried using `page.$(selector)` too, it returns an array containing ElementHandle and bunch of other stuuf whitch i don't fully understand what they are

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the elector is valid and returns someing?

Comment: yes, when the selector is invalid it returns an error but it's not the case

Comment: Please search the site before asking: [Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects), [Puppeteer returning empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017057/puppeteer-returning-empty-object), [Puppeteer page.evaluate returns empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386478/puppeteer-page-evaluate-returns-empty-object). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass an element handle from the browser to your puppeteer application. To transfer data from the browser puppeteer uses JSON.stringify and the element handle gets transformed into an empty object.

You could try to pass something else back to your application like the text content of the element.

```js
const browser = await pptr.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto("url")
const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector("selector").textContent
})
console.log(price)
```